# Using gdal_grid tool - set a defined extent

Tags: qgis, gdal, inverse-distance-weighted

I want to use the gdal_grid interpolation tool. Is it possible to set a defined extent?

Answer (score 1):

As documented in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html

```
-txe <xmin> <xmax>
Set georeferenced X extents of output file to be created.

-tye <ymin> <ymax>
Set georeferenced Y extents of output file to be created.
```